# updating individual elements in a vector

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm struggling with some logic/syntax....
I have simulation program which determines ink thickness as it travels through some rollers. I would like to add some functionality but can't seem to access the elements i'd like in my 1xN vectors.
i think my problem lies somewhere in here:

```
% # Iterate through timesteps
for tt = 2:nTimeSteps
% # Fill first roller with ink
rollers(1).ink = ones(1,nBins(1));

% # Rotate all rollers
for ii = 1:N
        rollers(ii).ink(:) = ...
            circshift(rollers(ii).ink(:),rollers(ii).rotDirection);
end

% # Update all roller-connections
for ii = 1:N
    for jj = 1:nBins(ii)
        if(rollers(ii).connections(jj) ~= 0)
            index1 = rollers(ii).connections(jj);
            index2 = find(ii == rollers(index1).connections);
            ink1 = rollers(ii).ink(jj);
            ink2 = rollers(index1).ink(index2);
            rollers(ii).ink(jj) = (ink1+ink2)/2;
            rollers(index1).ink(index2) = (ink1+ink2)/2;
        end
    end
end

% # Calculate average amount of ink on each roller
for ii = 1:N
    averageAmountOfInk(tt,ii) = mean(rollers(ii).ink);

end
end
```

The part where the first roller is 'filled with ink' - the roller is split into integer segments (nBins) and i would like to only have elements 13,14 and 15 with ink on them (the rest being zeros). 
The row vector length is 1x95. 
I can't seem to do this. I have tried various ways, most promising i thought was creating a matrix of zeros followed with something like:

```
rollers(1).ink(13) = 1;
```

etc...
immediately following the 'fill with ink' part.
This doesn't seem to do anything (not even an error)
I also have a similar problem with the output of the program - I'd like to only 'accept' ink on a percentage of the roller surface.(say around 70%)
The main frustration for me is that i know the data i'd like to manipulate is right there - i just can't get at it!
as always, any advice is hugely appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to create a 1x95 vector with all zeroes except for elements 13, 14 and 15:

With a temporary variable:

```
I = zeros(1, 95);
I(13 : 15) = 1;
```

Directly using concatenation:

```
[zeros(1, 12), ones(1, 3), zeros(1, 80)]
```

I'd go for concatenation:

```
rollers(1).ink = [zeros(1, 12), ones(1, 3), zeros(1, 80)];
```

Comment: @ Florian Brucker Thanks very much! I've searched many google pages (and SO!) looking for that syntax. It gives me direct access to the elements which is exactly what i wanted! Thanks and enjoy the rest of the day!